# TS1131 and TS1128 diffents between 2 const

Tags: typescript

in the code i find this part that work fine in ts compiler.

```
export const AbsPro: <State, Action>(props: ComponentProps<State, Action> & { children?: React.ReactNode })
    => React.ReactElement<any> = (props) => {
    const { r, s, m, c} = props.store;

    return (
        <context.Provider value={useStore(r, s, m)}>
            {props.children}
            </context.Provider>
    );
};
```

Now i want try rewrite this code with sono braces more:

```
export const Aa:<State, Action>(props: ComponentProps<State, Action> & { children?: React.ReactNode })=>{
    return React.ReactElement=(props)=>{ //line 164
    return (<div></div>)//line 165
    }
}
```

but the compiler say me

Error:(164, 5) TS1131: Property or signature expected.

Error:(167, 1) TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

if i remove the braces before line 164 and return in line 164, the compiler work fine, but now i can not understand the syntax

```
export const Aa:<State, Action>(props: ComponentProps<State, Action> & { children?: React.ReactNode })=>
     React.ReactElement=(props)=>{
    return (<div></div>)
    }
```

Someone can help me to understand why the compiler not recognize braces and return like correct?Can you help me to find documentation about this syntax?

Comment: @Ibottoni What I see, as the first problem, is that ComponentProps (which, I suppose, is a React type?) accepts only one Generic, instead of two. Moreover, with most recent `@types/react` you could use `React.PropsWithChildren<P>`, with `P` your props.

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti the first code work fine, the second it's only my test to expand with barces the code, but i can not understand not work

Comment: @Ibottoni look at the answer I gave you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `React.ReactElement` is the return type of the function. You are defining the type of const, which is a function that accepts `props` and returns a `React.ReactElement`. You cannot do `return React.ReactElement = (props) => {` because `return` is for runtime, `React.ReactElement` is for TS compile time.

Your code:

```js
export const AbsPro: <State, Action>(props: ComponentProps<State, Action> & { children?: React.ReactNode })
    => React.ReactElement<any> = (props) => {
    const { r, s, m, c} = props.store;

    return (
        <context.Provider value={useStore(r, s, m)}>
            {props.children}
        </context.Provider>
    );
};
```

Can be rewrited like this (more readable types):

```js
type AbsProFn = <State, Action>(props: ComponentProps<State, Action> & { children?: React.ReactNode }) => React.ReactElement<any>;

export const AbsPro: AbsProFn = (props) => {
    const { r, s, m, c} = props.store;

    return (
        <context.Provider value={useStore(r, s, m)}>
            {props.children}
        </context.Provider>
    );
};
```

Or

```js
export const AbsPro = <State, Action>(props: ComponentProps<State, Action> & { children?: React.ReactNode }): React.ReactElement<any> => {
    const { r, s, m, c} = props.store;

    return (
        <context.Provider value={useStore(r, s, m)}>
            {props.children}
        </context.Provider>
    );
};
```

If you want, with most `@types/react` installed, you can do also:

```js
export const AbsPro = <State, Action>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps<State, Action>>): React.ReactElement<any> => {
  const { r, s, m, c} = props.store;

  return (
      <context.Provider value={useStore(r, s, m)}>
          {props.children}
      </context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Usually I prefer return a `JSX.Element`, even it is maybe too generic sometimes.
Also I prefer using hoisted function instead consts because they are more readable.

```js
export function AbsPro<State, Action> (props: React.PropsWithChildren<ComponentProps<State, Action>>): React.ReactElement<any> {
  const { r, s, m, c} = props.store;

  return (
      <context.Provider value={useStore(r, s, m)}>
          {props.children}
      </context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Anyway, there's still one problem that I see:
`ComponentProps` Generic, which I suppose to be a React Type, accepts only one generic, not two. Probably it is related to most recent `@types/react`. You should check this because I don't know exactly what you want to achieve with that.

I've created you a code sandbox to see the examples all together: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-moon-ev3jl

Sadly, there, code is automatically formatted in a way I don't like and I don't know if this can be disabled.

Comment: yes, now i understand the definition in your example type AbsProFn = .... good!!thanks @Alexander